# A function that has both partial derivatives but is not differentiable or even continuous

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

> Let $f(x,y) = \dfrac{4xy(x+y)}{(x^2+y^2)} $, $f(0,0)=0$.

1. Show that if $f(x, y)$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$, then $\lim _{(h,h)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(h,h) = 0$.
2. Finally, show that $\lim _{(h,h)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(h,h)\ne0$  (does not equal to zero)

I used the limit definition to show that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable and equal to $0$. If I show that the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ exist and are $0$, shouldn't the $\lim _{(h,h)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(h,h)$ also be $0$ for $2$)?

edit: $f(x,y)$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, but the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ do exist and are equal to $0$. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: The map $f$ does not even be defined at $(0,0)$; how did you prove that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote it correctly? I also get 0 as a limit for number 2. If  x = y = h then this becomes $\frac{8h^3}{2h^2}=4h$ which goes to 0 as h goes to 0.

Comment: f(x,y) is not differentiable at (0,0), but the partial derivatives with respect to x and y do exist and are equal to 0. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I also got 0 as h goes to 0, but I'm confused as to why the questions contradict themselves.

Comment: The questions **do not** contradict themselves. 1) reads as: Show $P\to Q$. 2) reads as: Show $\lnot Q$. Where is the contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

$$(1.)$$Assume that $f(0,0)$ exists.If $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ then $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ .If $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ then $f(0,0)=\lim_{n \to \infty}f(1/n,1/n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}4/n=0.$  If $f(0,0)=0$ then $f$ IS continuous at $(0,0)$, for if $0<x^2+y^2<r$ then $|x y (x+y)|\le |x^2 y|+|y^2 x|\le (x^2 +y^2) \max(|x|,|y|)\le (x^2+y^2)r$, so $|f(x,y)|\le 4[(x^2+y^2)r]/[x^2+y^2]=4r$. In particular $f(h,h)$ DOES converge to $0$ as $h\to 0$ in non-zero values of $h$ regardless of the existence of $f(0,0)$. $$(2.)$$ Do not assume that $f(0,0)$ exists. Then nothing is known about whether or not $f$ is continuous or differentiable at $(0,0).$ $$(3.)$$ Assume that $f$ takes the value given by the initial formula for every $(x,y)$ in its domain.Then $f(0,0)$ does not exist, and so $f$ cannot be  continuous or differentiable or anything else at $(0,0)$.......I think this was the point :Don't make unjustifiable assumptions, no matter how small.If $f$ was not defined by me, I can't add extra info into the def'n  and still say that it's the same $f$.